# How to stop the extra request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

can someone tell why does this happens, I'm running a test and I have all these things coming out
[jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gNOi.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not very detailed. Please try to share more details and provide compete details of your test plan.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing us your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) (incomplete though) hence we cannot comment about "extra request" you're getting without seeing [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener output

The most common reasons for "extra requests" are:

- [Redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
- Calls for retrieving [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds)
- Outcome of [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) like [Loop](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) Controller

Comment: That picture is a part of the recording I made, just one clic and that's what happens. Although I'm not recording anything those things keeps showing up

Comment: They look like AJAX requests and WebSocket requests, I don't think you should be recording both types as proper replay will not be possible as for AJAX you should rather use [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) and for WebSocket a [special plugin](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/jmeter-websocket-samplers) is required. Again, it's only assumption based on requests paths in a single screenshot which doesn't even expose "Request "tab of the View Results Tree listener for body and headers